# Bonding multiple proxy server

Tags: linux, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I want to use multiple proxy server at the same time to speed my downloads. How can use multiple proxy at the same time. Reverse Proxy products such as haproxy nginx can use multiple proxy server but one proxy per session.

Client---haproxy---proxy1/proxy2/proxy3-----Webserver

But I want to balance one session. Imagine that I am downloading big file. In normal conditions this download comes to client throught only one proxy. But I want to devide this download in 3 part and utilize 3 proxy1-2-3.

Comment: Have you determined what the bottleneck is?  If it's client bandwidth, multiple proxy servers will not help.

Comment: In our infrastructure proxy is the bottleneck. Dont think it is a normal home/office internet connection. This is special infrastructure: We have two linux server and connected each other with a very slow link, this link is not a ethernet. it is a special connection, and very slow. And a special http proxy running on these linux servers to transfer files from other side. Connection speed is limited but we can use multiple lines and we can run multiple http proxy.
Client----->Linux(proxy)----SlowLink---->Linux----->Web server

Answer (score 1):

Extending Ladadadada's comment - it's very unlikely to be a CPU/Memory/storage IO issue - the bigest bottleneck is the network connection.

There's potentially 2 solutions to this, although you haven't provided any details of the infrastructure. If you are trying to provide a forward proxy service to a large number of users, and potentially on a number of different sites, and you want a distributed, caching forward proxy, then have a look at peering in Squid (although the growing use of SSL somewhat undermines this as a strategy).

If you have multiple internet links and want to make best use of them, then this is described in the [Linux Advanced Routing and Traffic Control Howto](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html). While this will speed up internet access, a single socket connection is tied to a specific connection - i.e. you won't notice much difference using SPDY, or downloading a large file (unless the there is already contention for bandwidth which is reduced by this approach).

It is possible to aggreegate the bandwidth of more than one WAN connection - although this requires some complex jiggery-pokery (multi-pathing) on the WAN side.

Comment: Thank you Symcbean. I am looking a similar solution like "routing for multiple uplinks/providers" or like "bonding network interfaces". But in my case, our connection is http proxy connection. We have very slow link, and custom http proxy is used to transfer files from other sites. We can use multiple lines and we can run multiple custom http proxy. Then I need to use all these custom http proxies in parallel